# databrick: spark read from Azure SQL DW error

Tags: databricks, azure-synapse

Currently in my notebook which is using

```
spark.read \  
  .format("com.databricks.spark.sqldw")\  
  .option("url", myurl)
```

to read data from Azure SQL DW . But now suddenly there is error : 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unexpected version returned: Microsoft Azure Synapse SQL Analytics - 10.0.10887.0 Dec 18 2019 21:47:50 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Make sure your JDBC url includes a "database=" option and that it points to a valid Azure SQL Data Warehouse name. This connector cannot be used for interacting with any other systems than DW (e.g. Azure SQL Databases).

what's happening ???

when i use

```
spark.read \  
  .format("jdbc")\  
  .option("url", myurl)
```

this is ok . why ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurred due to the change in the name of Azure Data Warehouse by Microsoft. I faced the same issue today and raised it to Microsoft Support. They are working on the rollback at the moment. Hope to see the resolution soon.

Comment: @mytabi The issue is fixed now.

Comment: still can't . just check

Comment: can you share what's your region of Azure dw and the code ?

Comment: @AasimKhan I am still facing the issue. Can you please confirm if this issue is resolved ?

Comment: @saurabhagarwal The issue is fixed and I am able to read/write the data to DWH. Maybe the region is you are on is still under the rollback process.  Wait for some time or else raise a ticket to Microsoft support. My Region is North Europe.